# How to change Query result into label and image in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, visual-studio, npgsql

***Language:***

C#

***What I want:***

To create a list of classes that have been selected from my 'combobox' and show them as labels. For each label there is an image file.

***What I have tried:***

I have tried to give my query a number that has been selected by the 'selectedindex' as below:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex  = result +1 ;
            CRUD.sql = "select  fillere.nom_fillere,class.nom_class from fillere,class " +
                       "where id_fillere ="+result+"";
           
        }
```

***The result I want:***

-class 1(folder image)
-class 2(folder image)
-class 3(folder image)

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with literal values!

Comment: Okey sir i take it in mind

Answer (score 1):

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection when you don't use SqlParameters.

I assume you understand how to retrieve the resultset from your query, so to answer your coding question, I would simply create a Label class for every result you want. For client side application I use WPF and Winforms, here is an example of using WPF:

```
var label = new Label();
label.Content = "Text you want to see...";

//Now add this control to a container control like a stack panel
stackPanel.Children.Add(label);
```

If you're using Winforms then a similar approach could be taken, you just need to create the label, populate the text/context properties and then add it to a container control, in Winform's you specify X/Y `Location`, the top left is 0,0 (X,Y), it's `Size` and then add it to the form.

WinForms:

```
Label myLabel = new Label();
myLabel.Text = "text in label";
myLabel .Location = new Point(25,25);
this.Controls.Add (myText);  //this = form1
```